# How to fix Static Driver Verifier results "error"

Tags: static-analysis, kmdf

I am trying to run the Static Driver Verifier on the "Kernel Mode Driver, USB (KMDF)" template project in Visual Studio 2019.

I select the Release configuration for x64 platform. I have only selected the "DriverCreate" rule. If I remove the call to `WdfDriverCreate` in `DriverEntry`, then I get "MustFix Defect" as result, with a clickable link that takes me to the report page.

If I leave the code as it is, with the call to `WdfDriverCreate` then the result is "error", and the result text is not clickable.

I can see that the build and link step is succesful in the UI, and this is also reflected in the file `smvbuild.log`.

`SDV-map.h` looks like this:

```
//Approved=false
//DriverEntry
#define fun_DriverEntry DriverEntry
//TestStaticVerifierEvtDevicePrepareHardware
#define fun_WDF_DEVICE_PREPARE_HARDWARE TestStaticVerifierEvtDevicePrepareHardware
//TestStaticVerifierEvtDeviceAdd
#define fun_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD TestStaticVerifierEvtDeviceAdd
//TestStaticVerifierEvtIoDeviceControl
#define fun_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_DEVICE_CONTROL TestStaticVerifierEvtIoDeviceControl
//TestStaticVerifierEvtIoStop
#define fun_WDF_IO_QUEUE_IO_STOP TestStaticVerifierEvtIoStop
//TestStaticVerifierEvtDriverContextCleanup
#define fun_WDF_OBJECT_CONTEXT_CLEANUP TestStaticVerifierEvtDriverContextCleanup
```

`sdv\results\drivercreate_SDV.xml` contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RuleResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <defect>false</defect>
  <Name>drivercreate</Name>
  <Result>SDV_TOOLERROR</Result>
  <IsPreCondition>false</IsPreCondition>
  <IsMustFix>true</IsMustFix>
  <isWarning>false</isWarning>
</RuleResult>
```

`SDV_TOOLERROR` looks suspicious, but I don't know what the problem is. How can I find more information about what the problem is here?

Comment: AFAIK `SDV_TOOLERROR` means that there was an error while executing the check - i.e. the check could not complete. For whatever reason. It does _not_ mean that there's something wrong in your driver.